# NextJS TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Anyone know the cause of this error?

```
warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#how-it-works      
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:262:55)
```

I have tried commenting out any components running in pages and creating a new NextJS-ts project from scratch but the error persists.

Comment: Do you use `.length` somewhere?

Comment: Nope. The project is completely empty.

Comment: Same problem. Just following the tutorial and at some point noticed it.

Comment: this probably happens on server. your logic on server is not correct. i had similar error once and I was implementing something wrong in api folder

Comment: Have you ran `npm install` in the folder yet?

Comment: @LongLegJim I tried that but the type error persists.

Comment: @Yilmaz But it's odd that it occurs when I comment out all logic with nothing present in the api folder. I assume there must be a problem with the config of the project but I created this project with the default command for creating NextJS ts projects.

Comment: @thatnewguy8 without seeing your code I cannot say anything for sure but guess. do u have github repo?

Comment: I am having the same problem at step 4 of this eggehad tutorial https://egghead.io/lessons/supabase-query-data-from-supabase-using-next-js - has anyone found a solution?

Comment: @Mel I ended up just recreating my application with the current version of Next and Node and I no longer got the error warning.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, seems like a next 13 bug. It doesn't seem to be breaking anything that I can tell.

It is probably the following `const hasUpdates = Boolean(updatedModules.length);` just needs to be `const hasUpdates = Boolean(updatedModules && updatedModules.length);`

Answer (score 0):

I checked this directory:"./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:262:55" in v "13.0.1" and v"13.0.3". In both this function is defined same:

```
function tryApplyUpdates(onHotUpdateSuccess) {
    if (!module.hot) {
       // HotModuleReplacementPlugin is not in Webpack configuration.
       console.error('HotModuleReplacementPlugin is not in Webpack configuration.');
       // window.location.reload();
       return;
    }
    if (!isUpdateAvailable() || !canApplyUpdates()) {
        (0, _client).onBuildOk();
        return;
        }

   function handleApplyUpdates(err, updatedModules) {
        if (err || hadRuntimeError || !updatedModules) {
            if (err) {
                console.warn('[Fast Refresh] performing full reload\n\n' + "Fast Refresh will perform a full reload when you edit a file that's imported by modules outside of the React rendering tree.\n" + 'You might have a file which exports a React component but also exports a value that is imported by a non-React component file.\n' + 'Consider migrating the non-React component export to a separate file and importing it into both files.\n\n' + 'It is also possible the parent component of the component you edited is a class component, which disables Fast Refresh.\n' + 'Fast Refresh requires at least one parent function component in your React tree.');
            } else if (hadRuntimeError) {
                console.warn('[Fast Refresh] performing full reload because your application had an unrecoverable error');
            }
            performFullReload(err);
            return;
        }
        const hasUpdates = Boolean(updatedModules.length);
        if (typeof onHotUpdateSuccess === 'function') {
            // Maybe we want to do something.
            onHotUpdateSuccess(hasUpdates);
        }
        if (isUpdateAvailable()) {
            // While we were updating, there was a new update! Do it again.
            // However, this time, don't trigger a pending refresh state.
            tryApplyUpdates(hasUpdates ? undefined : onBeforeHotUpdate, hasUpdates ? _client.onBuildOk : onHotUpdateSuccess);
        } else {
            (0, _client).onBuildOk();
            if (process.env.__NEXT_TEST_MODE) {
                afterApplyUpdates(()=>{
                    if (self.__NEXT_HMR_CB) {
                        self.__NEXT_HMR_CB();
                        self.__NEXT_HMR_CB = null;
                    }
                });
            }
        } 
        // in here its call handleApplyUpdates
     }
```

this is just definition of the function. But difference is when call it: In v"13.0.1", this is how they call

```
module.hot.check(/* autoApply */ true).then((updatedModules)=>{
    // without any check "updatedModules" is just passed assumet it is an array
    handleApplyUpdates(null, updatedModules);
}, (err)=>{
    handleApplyUpdates(err, null);
});
```

in v"13.0.3", they made a type checking first

```
 module.hot.check(/* autoApply */ false).then((updatedModules)=>{
        if (typeof onBeforeHotUpdate === 'function') {
            const hasUpdates = Boolean(updatedModules.length);
            onBeforeHotUpdate(hasUpdates);
        }
        return module.hot.apply();
    }).then((updatedModules)=>{
        handleApplyUpdates(null, updatedModules);
    }, (err)=>{
        handleApplyUpdates(err, null);
    });
```

Probably it was a bug in your next.js version. if you use v"13.0.3", it should work

Comment: I use 13.0.4 and I see the same warning.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `export default function Page(){}`

**Change this to an es6 function** `const Page = () => {}`

And add `export default Page` to the bottom.
I did this for the Layout as well.

This worked for me somehow :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I ran into this same issue. I was also following the tutorial with the exception of creating an about page instead of an index. When I used a regular function in about.js I received the same error. The function looked like this:

```
function AboutPage() {
    return <div>The About Page</div>;
}

export default AboutPage;
```

When I changed it to an arrow function the error went away. The arrow function looked like this:

```
const AboutPage = () => {
    return <div>The About Page and Stuff</div>;
}

export default AboutPage;
```

I'm not sure why next threw an error on the regular function, but changing it to an arrow functions seems to have done the trick.