# Nextjs v 13 - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

Tags: next.js

I am trying to learn how to make a nextjs app with this [egghead tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/supabase-query-data-from-supabase-using-next-js). I am stuck on lesson 4 which shows how to read data from a supabase db.

I think the issue might have something to do with a change in nextjs v 13. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74415937/nextjs-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-length) has a suggestion, which is to change the Home function into a const with an arrow in it. I tried it as follows but still can't get the code to work as demonstrated.

```
import { supabase } from '../utils/supabase'

const Home = ({lessons}) => {
  
  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center py-2">
      {lessons.map( lesson => (
        <p key={lesson.id}>{lesson.title}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const { data: lessons } = await supabase.from('lesson').select('*')

  return { props: { lessons } }
}
```

My error message is in the browser is:

> Error: Failed to fetch update manifest Internal Server Error at
> http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1668894571923:1188:37

My error message in the terminal is:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') at eval
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:262:55)

Does anyone know what the changes are that are required in order to update an outdated nextjs to work with next v13? I can't make sense of the nextjs update documentation.

Comment: is this the component that causing error? if you comment out all the functions just leave an empty compoent, will it still throw same error?

Comment: It's the only thing in the app so far. I can type text above and below the supabase call and the text renders on the screen but the supabase call shows an error

Comment: did you setup experimental app directory?

Comment: I don't know what that means. I followed the instructions in steps 1 - 4 of the egghead tutorial

Comment: what is your next version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug caused by v13.0.3 of Next.js. I opened a PR (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/43145) with a potential fix.

In the meantime, you may be able to get around this by downgrading to 13.0.2.

Comment: Hi @ColinKing, thank you for the suggestion. I tried changing the next version from latest to the one you suggested. I get no errors in terminal or console, but I also can't read the data from the supabase call.

Comment: When I console.log(lessons) I get an empty array. I have 2 entries in the supabase